# Reading Assembly Bomb

Tags: assembly, x86-64, disassembly

Im having trouble understanding these 2 lines of code. This is from a binary bomb lab

```
# regs
rbx            0x0  0
rbp            0x7fffffffe910 <--points to a seq of 1 2 3 4 5 6  

# code
add    0x0(%rbp,%rbx,4),%eax
cmp    %eax,0x4(%rbp,%rbx,4)
```

I think this is just doing `2 + 0 * 4`. I should be in the second number, since I jumped the first bomb, but I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: @Mephy: He's showing the contents of rbx and rbp, then the disassembly of two instructions that use those registers.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't give the contents of eax.  Watch out for integer overflow.

You also didn't tell us whether `rbp` is pointing to a sequence of increasing bytes, 32bit-ints, or what.  (I assume you meant points to when you said "contains", since it looks like a pointer to stack memory and the code uses it as a pointer.)

Since `rbx` is zero, it's equivalent to:

```
add    (%rbp),%eax             # eax += *rbp
cmp    %eax,0x4(%rbp)          # set flags from *(rbp+4) - eax.  (+4B = one 32bit integer)
#  e.g. jl will branch if *(rbp+4) < eax
```

Comment: I've tried to look at the content of %eax but it won't appear on the registers.

Comment: @De-Novo: you know that %eax is the low32 of %rax, right?  Not sure what you mean by "won't appear on the registers".  In gdb, `print $eax` or `print $rax` both work.  `layout asm`  `layout reg`  of course doesn't have separate displays for `eax`, `ax`, and `ah` / `al`.  `edb` might be good for this, since you don't have source code, and probably not even symbols.

Comment: Thanks yea I didn't  know that.